# Angular BehaviorSubject is triggering subscription only once on component loading

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a service responsible of toggle a sidenav between components

**FormMenuService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FormMenuService {

    openMenu: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    toggle(): void {
        this.openMenu.next({ test: 'test' });
    }
}
```

**Form.component**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.formMenuService.openMenu.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.sidenavMenu.open();
  }
```

In **Toolbar.Component** I'm triggering the FormMenuService

```
openFormMenu() {
  this.formMenuService.toggle()
}
```

When I run `openFormMenu` the service is workig also. But in Form.component the subscription is not triggered.

The subscription is only triggered once , on component loading with `null` value , which is the initial value of the `SubjectBehavior`. that's mean that the service declaration is working.

I don't know why the subscription is not working after initial load

I have also tried iniside `ngOnInit` not working too

Answer (score 2):

Please validate that the service is imported only once in the providers, if the service is in multiple providers you might get this problem.

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [TestService], // <- this Test service should only be added to providers once to ensure a singleton class is used!
  imports: [TestComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from test!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    <app-test></app-test>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.testService.openMenu.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz showing this problem happening](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-exezzg)

[proper working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wckgg6)

An alternate will be to just give

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FormMenuService {

    openMenu: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    toggle(): void {
        this.openMenu.next({ test: 'test' });
    }
}
```

[stackblitz providedIn root](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1bmqvo)